# What is the best way to repeat a single declaration in Sass?

Tags: css, sass

In my project I have many elements that will take this property `text-align: center`.
How can we avoid writing this declaration in all elements using Sass?

In other words, is there more efficient way to do something like this:

```css
.one {
  text-align: center;
}
.two {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: its the same u give this property a class like bootstrap text-center

Comment: Thanks @RadiantAhmed for answering, but I try to avoid using non-semantic class names.

Comment: It might seem ugly and too much work but in a lot of cases, repeating yourself is a good thing. It's nice to split code into modules(multiple files) and it's nice to be able to change one of those modules later on without having to worry about all other modules. Only if you're certain a lot of modules will always need the same style, a mixin is nice to use. There is a fine line between repeating too much or too little, it can be different in each project.

Comment: Thanks @René, you made it clear for me. This is the best answer.

Comment: @MoaazBhnas Mine wasn't really an answer ;) You should probably accept Sam's answer as its technically the most efficient for what you asked. I merely gave some insights in alternative thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the power of pure CSS!

```
.one, .two {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mixins

example

Declare

```
@mixin centerAlign {
  text-align : center;
}
```

Use

```
.one {
  @include centerAlign;
}
.two {
   @include centerAlign;
}
```

Comment: dont you think still he have to write it again and again.??by the way nice answer

Comment: Thanks for answering @Deepak but what is the point? I'll still be repeating myself.

Comment: Don't consider like this example which has a single rule but consider something which has multiple rules but used in different places.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this

```
.text-center{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Include text-center in html code where you want to display center align.
ex

```
<p class='text-center'>...</p>

<div class='text-center'>...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use extensions:

```
.center-align {
  text-align:center
}

.one, .two {
  @extend .center-align;
  /*additional styling*/
}
```

It pretty much works out the same way as has been previouly posted

Comment: Might be nicer to use a placeholder http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors . Also, there is a difference in output between using extend and mixins(extend is usually a bit more efficient)